# Prove Logical Operations Using Inference Rules

Tags: math, logical-operators, proof

Premise 1: `p ∧ q`

Premise 2: `q → r`

Premise 3: `s → ¬r`

Premise 4: `¬r → ¬u`

Premise 5: `t ∨ s`

Premise 6: `t → ¬p ∨ U`

Prove: `u ∧ q`

Does anybody know how to solve this proof using rules of inference? I know the rules of inference like modus ponens/tollens but I am not sure how to use them here. I am still beginning to learn these types of proofs.

Can anybody show me how to complete this? Thanks.

Comment: You could always set up truth tables, but I suspect you are looking for formal mathematical proofs.

Comment: Correct, Tim. Otherwise I would.

Comment: There are several different possible sets of inference rules you could be using, including Hilbert’s or Natural Reasoning.  What are your axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `p ∧ q → p` and `p ∧ q → q`, by Premise 1 both `p` and `q` are true.

By Premise 2 we now know that `r` is true.

By Premise 3, `r → ¬s`, so `s` is false.

Then, by Premise 5, `t` must be true.

Now, by Premise 6, `¬p ∨ u` is true, but since `p` is true, it is `u` which must be true.

Finally, both `q` and `u` are true and so it is `u ∧ q`.

(Also note that Premise 4 is not needed)

Comment: Thanks man! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to figure out the laws and make a nice proof!